# Angular velocity of a conic pendulum

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, mathematical-physics, home-experiment

Some year 12 circular motion questions for you. I have an experiment where an object of m mass is tied to a string of L length. Centripetal force (Fc) is known along with m and L. The object is spun around at constant angular velocity horizontal/parallel to the ground. I am comparing two models. Model 1: gravity is ignored and the object is assumed to be moving in a perfect circle. Model 2: gravity is considered and it becomes a conic pendulum problem. I was deriving the math equations and both equations from each math model simplified to what is effectively the same thing. I cannot believe this to be true which makes me think there is an error in my working. My working is attached as an image. Any help is much appreciated. Thank you.

[image: My working]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure to get what you find surprising. Is it that in both cases, you get that $\omega = \sqrt{\frac{F_T}{m l}}$, where $F_T$ is the (total) rope tension and $l$ the rope length? Because in the second case, this comes from the fact that you can project both $F_T$ and $l$ on the plane of motion without changing the ratio between the two. So that in the end $\sqrt{\frac{F_T}{m l}}=\sqrt{\frac{F_{T,\mathrm{plane}}}{m r}}=\omega$ (the last equality comes from an analysis of the motion in the plane).

Besides, the two situations are quite different. In the first case, no matter the initial velocity you're giving to the mass, it will follow a uniform circular motion with that same velocity (assuming the rope is perfectly inelastic). But in the second case, because we also have $F_T = \frac{mg}{\cos(\theta)}$ needed to compensate gravity, we have that $\omega$ actually does not depend on the initial velocity but rather on $\theta$ only:

$$\omega = \sqrt{\frac{g}{l \cos(\theta)}} \geq \sqrt{\frac{g}{l}}$$

But for this circular motion to hold you also need to provide the right initial velocity (both on terms of direction and norm). Assuming that the initial velocity is oriented correctly (tangent to the circle of radius $r = l \cos(\theta)$), you need to have $v_0 = \omega r = \sqrt{\frac{g \cos(\theta)}{l}}$.

So I would say the two situations are quite different, the second one being much more constrained. If the initial velocity is not right, the motion will not be circular (constant height) but rather will oscillate between different heights with a changing angular velocity.